# How to exclude Bootstrap's CSS from encapsulation in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

Component imports Bootstrap to reference variables or mixins:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

HTML contains custom CSS elements but mostly standard Bootstrap elements:

```
<div class="container container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-3 h-100">
```

The view encapsulation generates CSS from Bootstrap classes, and I would like to avoid it:

```
.h-100[_ngcontent-ukx-c19] {
    height: 100% !important;
}
.row[_ngcontent-ukx-c19] {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));
    margin-right: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
    margin-left: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
}
```

Is it possible to exclude Bootstrap from View Encapsulation and still be able to import Bootstrap into a component with enabled Encapsulation?

EDIT: Here is used `angular.json`: https://github.com/maciejmiklas/ng-doom/blob/20230124/angular.json

Comment: generally, when you use bootstrap.css you want to use in all your application, so you should add in angular.json. in the array "styles": "projects" --> "ClientApp" --> "architect" --> "build" --> "styles"

Comment: I feel you need **not** import `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap` in your components.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it cannot be done. Here is a similar problem: [Angular2: How to use bootstrap-sass with @extend and mixins in Angular-CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071790/angular2-how-to-use-bootstrap-sass-with-extend-and-mixins-in-angular-cli)

As Eliseo pointed out - I have to remove bootstrap import from my component, which means I cannot use bootstrap imports inside components scss.

Answer (score 0):

there is a section in angular.json called `build`->`options`->`styles`. styles listed there won't be encapsulated

Comment: I have it there, and it's not working: https://github.com/maciejmiklas/ng-doom/blob/20230124/angular.json . Probably, because my component imports bootstrap, this is necessary to use its variables/mixins.